# Query#scroll() was deprecated for what in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I found that [`Query#scroll()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#scroll--) is marked as deprecated in Javadoc.

Unfortunately, authors forgot to write, what is current alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole interface is deprecated. At the top of the javadoc you'll see that instead of [org.hibernate.Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html), you should be using (or moving to) [org.hibernate.query.Query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html).

All the methods should be usable as is, it's just the interface that will be removed eventually, so you should move to using the new one.

> NOTE: Query is deprecated, and slated for removal in 6.0. For the time
>   being we leave all methods defined on Query rather than here because
>   it was previously the public API so we want to leave that unchanged in
>   5.x. For 6.0 we will move those methods here and then delete that class.

Comment: So, what is instead of `scroll`?

Comment: Nothing. It's still a valid method. Just the interface that is deprecated.

Comment: Method is deprecated too, please see the link.

Comment: All the methods are deprecated. The whole interface is deprecated. It will be removed. Use the new interface where necessary.

Comment: But how do you sure that method is not deprecated if it is labelled deprecated in Javadoc?

Comment: Because of the note in the newer interface's javadoc. Which I included at the end of my response.